# Javascript function to convert indian currency numbers to words with paise support

Tags: javascript

> **Is there any faster solution than this?**

After spending some time in googling and playing with other's code, I made a quick fix and reusable function works well for numbers up to 99,99,99,999.

`number2text(1234.56);` will return `ONE THOUSAND TWO HUNDRED AND THIRTY-FOUR RUPEE AND FIFTY-SIX PAISE ONLY` .

```
function number2text(value) {
    var fraction = Math.round(frac(value)*100);
    var f_text  = "";

    if(fraction > 0) {
        f_text = "AND "+convert_number(fraction)+" PAISE";
    }

    return convert_number(value)+" RUPEE "+f_text+" ONLY";
}

function frac(f) {
    return f % 1;
}

function convert_number(number)
{
    if ((number < 0) || (number > 999999999)) 
    { 
        return "NUMBER OUT OF RANGE!";
    }
    var Gn = Math.floor(number / 10000000);  /* Crore */ 
    number -= Gn * 10000000; 
    var kn = Math.floor(number / 100000);     /* lakhs */ 
    number -= kn * 100000; 
    var Hn = Math.floor(number / 1000);      /* thousand */ 
    number -= Hn * 1000; 
    var Dn = Math.floor(number / 100);       /* Tens (deca) */ 
    number = number % 100;               /* Ones */ 
    var tn= Math.floor(number / 10); 
    var one=Math.floor(number % 10); 
    var res = ""; 

    if (Gn>0) 
    { 
        res += (convert_number(Gn) + " CRORE"); 
    } 
    if (kn>0) 
    { 
            res += (((res=="") ? "" : " ") + 
            convert_number(kn) + " LAKH"); 
    } 
    if (Hn>0) 
    { 
        res += (((res=="") ? "" : " ") +
            convert_number(Hn) + " THOUSAND"); 
    } 

    if (Dn) 
    { 
        res += (((res=="") ? "" : " ") + 
            convert_number(Dn) + " HUNDRED"); 
    } 


    var ones = Array("", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX","SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN", "TWELVE", "THIRTEEN","FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN", "EIGHTEEN","NINETEEN"); 
var tens = Array("", "", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FOURTY", "FIFTY", "SIXTY","SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY"); 

    if (tn>0 || one>0) 
    { 
        if (!(res=="")) 
        { 
            res += " AND "; 
        } 
        if (tn < 2) 
        { 
            res += ones[tn * 10 + one]; 
        } 
        else 
        { 

            res += tens[tn];
            if (one>0) 
            { 
                res += ("-" + ones[one]); 
            } 
        } 
    }

    if (res=="")
    { 
        res = "zero"; 
    } 
    return res;
}
```

Comment: wat exactly u mean by "fast solution"?

Comment: @Arvind : there are 3 functions and complex process ! fast means best optimization in terms of length of code as well execution

Answer (score 8):

INDIAN **PRICE** CURRENCY BY WORDS BASED ON GIVEN NUMBER

125,00,00,000

One Hundred and Twenty Five Crore

```js
function price_in_words(price) {
  var sglDigit = ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"],
    dblDigit = ["Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"],
    tensPlace = ["", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"],
    handle_tens = function(dgt, prevDgt) {
      return 0 == dgt ? "" : " " + (1 == dgt ? dblDigit[prevDgt] : tensPlace[dgt])
    },
    handle_utlc = function(dgt, nxtDgt, denom) {
      return (0 != dgt && 1 != nxtDgt ? " " + sglDigit[dgt] : "") + (0 != nxtDgt || dgt > 0 ? " " + denom : "")
    };

  var str = "",
    digitIdx = 0,
    digit = 0,
    nxtDigit = 0,
    words = [];
  if (price += "", isNaN(parseInt(price))) str = "";
  else if (parseInt(price) > 0 && price.length <= 10) {
    for (digitIdx = price.length - 1; digitIdx >= 0; digitIdx--) switch (digit = price[digitIdx] - 0, nxtDigit = digitIdx > 0 ? price[digitIdx - 1] - 0 : 0, price.length - digitIdx - 1) {
      case 0:
        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, ""));
        break;
      case 1:
        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
        break;
      case 2:
        words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] && 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : "") : "");
        break;
      case 3:
        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Thousand"));
        break;
      case 4:
        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
        break;
      case 5:
        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Lakh"));
        break;
      case 6:
        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
        break;
      case 7:
        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Crore"));
        break;
      case 8:
        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
        break;
      case 9:
        words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] || 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : " Crore") : "")
    }
    str = words.reverse().join("")
  } else str = "";
  return str

}

console.log(price_in_words(1250000000));
console.log(price_in_words(9999999999));
```

Comment: This is not working properly with decimal number. For `e.g.` `12.99` it returns `Twelve Thousand undefined Hundred and Ninety Nine `.

Answer (score 1):

The second comment has the solution. Just use:

```
var num =129000.9889;
var splittedNum =num.toString().split('.')
var nonDecimal=splittedNum[0]
var decimal=splittedNum[1]
var value=price_in_words(Number(nonDecimal))+" and 
"+price_in_words(Number(decimal))+" paise"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertNumberToWords(amount) {
    var words = new Array();
    words[0] = '';
    words[1] = 'One';
    words[2] = 'Two';
    words[3] = 'Three';
    words[4] = 'Four';
    words[5] = 'Five';
    words[6] = 'Six';
    words[7] = 'Seven';
    words[8] = 'Eight';
    words[9] = 'Nine';
    words[10] = 'Ten';
    words[11] = 'Eleven';
    words[12] = 'Twelve';
    words[13] = 'Thirteen';
    words[14] = 'Fourteen';
    words[15] = 'Fifteen';
    words[16] = 'Sixteen';
    words[17] = 'Seventeen';
    words[18] = 'Eighteen';
    words[19] = 'Nineteen';
    words[20] = 'Twenty';
    words[30] = 'Thirty';
    words[40] = 'Forty';
    words[50] = 'Fifty';
    words[60] = 'Sixty';
    words[70] = 'Seventy';
    words[80] = 'Eighty';
    words[90] = 'Ninety';
    amount = amount.toString();
    var atemp = amount.split(".");
    var number = atemp[0].split(",").join("");
    var n_length = number.length;
    var words_string = "";
    if (n_length <= 9) {
        var n_array = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var received_n_array = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < n_length; i++) {
            received_n_array[i] = number.substr(i, 1);
        }
        for (var i = 9 - n_length, j = 0; i < 9; i++, j++) {
            n_array[i] = received_n_array[j];
        }
        for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < 9; i++, j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                if (n_array[i] == 1) {
                    n_array[j] = 10 + parseInt(n_array[j]);
                    n_array[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        value = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                value = n_array[i] * 10;
            } else {
                value = n_array[i];
            }
            if (value != 0) {
                words_string += words[value] + " ";
            }
            if ((i == 1 && value != 0) || (i == 0 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Crores ";
            }
            if ((i == 3 && value != 0) || (i == 2 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Lakhs ";
            }
            if ((i == 5 && value != 0) || (i == 4 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Thousand ";
            }
            if (i == 6 && value != 0 && (n_array[i + 1] != 0 && n_array[i + 2] != 0)) {
                words_string += "Hundred and ";
            } else if (i == 6 && value != 0) {
                words_string += "Hundred ";
            }
        }
        words_string = words_string.split("  ").join(" ");
    }
    return words_string;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. There is no link.

Comment: The answer given is very good and works correctly. Some improvements can be done: (1) The value after decimal should be converted to paise (2) It is easy to handle beyond nine digits by using recursion, so make it work for 12 or 15 digits.

Answer (score 0):

below function support amount upto 24 digits followed by 2 decimals

```
    function price_in_words(price) {
    price = price.toString();
    var sglDigit = ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"],
        dblDigit = ["Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"],
        tensPlace = ["", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"],
        handle_tens = function(dgt, prevDgt) {
            return 0 == dgt ? "" : " " + (1 == dgt ? dblDigit[prevDgt] : tensPlace[dgt])
        },
        handle_utlc = function(dgt, nxtDgt, denom) {
            return (0 != dgt && 1 != nxtDgt ? " " + sglDigit[dgt] : "") + (0 != nxtDgt || dgt > 0 ? " " + denom : "")
        };

    var str = "",
        digitIdx = 0,
        digit = 0,
        nxtDigit = 0,
        words = [];
    var re = /(0|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d+)?/g
    if (re.test(price)) {
        var arr = price.split('.');
        price = arr[0];
        for (digitIdx = price.length - 1; digitIdx >= 0; digitIdx--) {
            switch (digit = price[digitIdx] - 0, nxtDigit = digitIdx > 0 ? price[digitIdx - 1] - 0 : 0, price.length - digitIdx - 1) {
                case 0:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, ""));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] && 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : "") : "");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Thousand"));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Lakh"));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;
                case 7:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Crore"));
                    break;
                case 8:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;

                case 9:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Arab"));
                    break;
                case 10:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;

                case 11:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Kharab"));
                    break;
                case 12:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;

                case 13:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Nil"));
                    break;
                case 14:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;

                case 15:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Padma"));
                    break;
                case 16:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;

                case 17:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Shankh"));
                    break;
                case 18:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;

                case 19:
                    words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] && 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : "") : "");
                    break;
                case 20:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Thousand"));
                    break;
                case 21:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;
                case 22:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Lakh"));
                    break;
                case 23:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;
            }
        }
        str = words.reverse().join("")
        if(arr.length > 1)
        {
            price = arr[1];
            words= null;
            for (digitIdx = price.length - 1; digitIdx >= 0; digitIdx--) {          
                case 0:
                    words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, ""));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] && 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : "") : "");
                    break;
            }
            str += " Rupees " + words.reverse().join("") + " Paise"
        }
    } else str = "";
    return str

}

console.log(price_in_words("1.00"));
console.log(price_in_words("12"));
console.log(price_in_words("123"));
console.log(price_in_words("1234"));
console.log(price_in_words("12345"));
console.log(price_in_words("123456"));
console.log(price_in_words("1234567"));
console.log(price_in_words("12345678"));
console.log(price_in_words("123456789"));
console.log(price_in_words("1234567890"));
console.log(price_in_words("12345678901"));
console.log(price_in_words("123456789012"));
console.log(price_in_words("1234567890123"));
console.log(price_in_words("12345678901234"));
console.log(price_in_words("123456789012345"));
console.log(price_in_words("1234567890123456"));
console.log(price_in_words("12345678901234567"));
console.log(price_in_words("123456789012345678"));
console.log(price_in_words("1234567890123456789"));
console.log(price_in_words("12345678901234567890"));
console.log(price_in_words("123456789012345678901"));
console.log(price_in_words("1234567890123456789012"));
console.log(price_in_words("12345678901234567890123"));
console.log(price_in_words("123456789012345678901234"));
console.log(price_in_words("1234567890123456789012345"));
console.log(price_in_words("12345678901234567890123456"));
```

Comment: The last for loop have case statement without the switch case. This code will not run only.